# Is the PoEPi available or is it still in development?

Tags: pi-zero-w, alternative-power

I was looking around for a way to power the Pi Zero W over PoE in a compact package, and I came across [this board](https://hackaday.io/project/9455-poepi-pi-zero-power-over-ethernet-with-phy).  It does exactly what I want, but I can't find it being crowdfunded, talked about, for sale anywhere, or even any information elsewhere.  I have not found similar or competing boards either.  I have found some PoE hats for the full sized Pis though, but those are too big, expensive, and cumbersome for my project.

The author of the project mentions buying the "assembled boards" from Digikey, but it seems like he is custom ordering them.  I thought Digikey was a parts supplier, not a small run manufacturer.

Is the PoEPi available as a product or kit?  Did the project die?  Looking at the comments on the project, there haven't been any updates in a while.

Are there any comparable boards or widgets to bring power and Ethernet to a Pi Zero over PoE?  I'd prefer the same or similar form factor.

I've come across some [power splitters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MDLUSE7) that take the P off the PoE, and then give you the E, but then you need another widget to get Ethernet into the Pi Zero.

Comment: It says right there that the project is still waiting for first prototype boards. So it is not available, you may consider using a passive splitter like [this jobbie](http://a.co/aiPXqYZ)

Comment: Sorry, but shopping recommendations are explicitly [off-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: How is this a shopping question?

Comment: -> https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1008/5538